# scope of friend function

Tags: c++, g++, friend

I have two classes, **one** and **two**, each having a **friend** member function with an pointer to the other. The first header file is as per below:

```
#ifndef FIRSTCLASS_H
#define FIRSTCLASS_H

class two;

class one {

private:
int one_data;

public:
friend void second_data (two *);
};

#endif
```

The second header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef SECONDCLASS_H
#define SECONDCLASS_H

class one;

class two {

private:
int two_data;

public:
friend void first_data (one *);
};

#endif
```

The actual functions are in a third .cpp file. I wrote the functions with appropriate class qualifier, it gives an compilation error. I am using g++. The functions are as follows:

```
#include "firstclass.h"
#include "secondclass.h"

void two::first_data (one * class1) {

}

 void one::second_data (two * class2) {

}
```

The errors are as followa:

```
 error:no ‘void two::first_data (one*)’ member function declared in class ‘two’ 
 error: no ‘void one::second_data(two*)’ member function declared in class ‘one’
```

When I drop the class qualifier before the function name, the code compiles. The modified functions are as follows:

```
 void first_data(one * class1) {

 }

 void second_data(two * class2) {

 }
```

I am new to c++ and I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong in the first case. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you declare is freestanding functions as friends of your classes.
They are not really members of any class.

```
friend void first_data (one *);
```

declares a freestanding function `first_data` as friend of your class, it does not mean `first_data` is a member function of your class. Hence when you define the function in cpp file the compiler complains that the function was never declared.

Also,

```
void two::first_data (one * class1){}

Returntype ClassName ScopeResolution FunctionSignature
```

`two::` tells compiler the functions belongs to this particular class, it is not namespace specification, it is class qualification.

Comment: I think I understood my mistake (and what you are trying to say :) )

Answer (score 2):

That's not a `namespace`, that's a `class` qualifier.

```
void two::first_data (one * class1) {

}
```

defines the method `first_data` from class `two`.

However, you declared as friend the free function `first_data`:

```
friend void first_data (one *);
```

which is not the same. If you want free functions as friends, use the `friend` declaration you already have. If not, you can declare methods as friends similary:

```
friend void two::first_data (one *);
```

Comment: sorry, what i meant is class qualifier. I should edit the question

Comment: but first_data () is indeed a member of class two. So shouldn't two::first_data(one *) compile?

Comment: @maths-help-seeker no, you didn't declare members as friends, but free functions.

Comment: I am wrong in this declaration: friend void second_data (two *)?

Comment: @maths-help-seeker you're not wrong, but it doesn't do what you think. It declares the free function `second_data` as friend, not the member `second_data` of `one`.

Comment: @maths-help-seeker for that, you need `friend void one::second_data (two *)`.